# Rails3 populate an association from link_to without using a hidden field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I set the value of :foo_id without using a hidden form field? Can I somehow pass the value from a link_to, to the new method without exposing it on the client side?

ie: click on "Create foo" for "bar 5" and it passes this variable to the new method without the possibility of the client modifying it?

Sorry if I cant be more verbose with this question, If I could formulate it better Im sure Google or SO would have helped me by now.

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

Comment: Whatever you send to a users browser is "exposed". No matter if it's part of an url or a hidden field in a form, it can be changed. Don't trust anything that comes from a browser.

Comment: Then how can I validate that the id I sent the browser is the same id that they are returning? I mean Im sure I could put it in the session, and not even pass it via the client. Ive done similar stuff in PHP, Im just wondering if there was an easy "rails" way to do this?

Comment: @throsten, exposed yes. But you could encrypt the data self (since it does not need to be altered by the client).

Comment: Yes, validating against a session would be possible. In general you will always check permissions. Say somebody asks to see a certain order, you always check if he has permission to see this order and only then display it. In every controller and action that allows access to a resource. In this case it doesn't matter much if somebody changes an id. If he changes it to something valid, he get to see the stuff.

Comment: @Rogier: Yes, to some extend. But even if you encrypt such an id, you at least have to handle the case where the encrypted string is changed and becomes invalid. If you want a reasonable encryption, you need a minimum length of the encrypted string. You would have to make some 20 char string just to send an id. This may make sense sometimes, but my guess is that the question just asks for how to correctly handle 'normal' ids.

Comment: I accepted the answer below just because it fits all use cases, from "normal" ids to super secret secure stuff as well. I was however hoping that there was some easy way to have rails just make sure if the param in the link said "5" when it was sent out, that it will only accept "5" when it comes back in via post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pseudo key/token table.

Its a simple 2 column table. You generate a token an store it together with the key. You send the token as hidden field. On returning the the token you fetch the correct key, then remove the token/key record.

> http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom

Comment: That's it, I just needed a nudge in the right direction. Thanks.